# Is there anyway to mock Singleton Class with Injection In Scala Test using ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have one singleton Class let say,

```
class DbConnect @Inject()(val dbconfig: Config){

 private val dbName = dbconfig.getString("dbName")
 ....

}
```

and in Test File :

```
class DbTest {
     private val dbConnect: DbConnect = mock[DbConnect]
     ...

}
```

This Mock Creation Failed.

Comment: 1. Could you please add full stacktrace?
2. Why do you think that DbConnect is a singleton?

Comment: I am just giving an example. I have this type of scenario.
Dependency itself has one dependency so how can I mock with that?

In ClassA , mock[B] where B is dependent on C.

this type of scenario I have.